# Moving an HTML+javascript page to iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have an existing website composed of individual pages (each page is a different tool that requires some user input (ie forms), and each with it's own set of javascript functions to populate dropdown lists, etc on that page). Each of the tools is accessed from the main index.html.

Instead of each tool being its own "stand-alone" page that is invoked from index.html, I'd like each tool to be displayed in an iFrame instead on the main page. This way the main page remains static, while only updating the iframe with whatever tool the user selects. So say on the main index page, I have a 3 tools menu (collect logs, collect KPIs, collect status), along with an iFrame. If the user selects collect logs for example, the menu containing "collect logs" stays there, but the "collect logs" page is displayed in the iFrame.

My problem is that all the HTML content works fine, but none of the javascript code in the selected tool page works (ie none of the drop downs get populated since it's the javascript code in the page that does that by reading a file on the server).

Is there an easy way to port each tool page (html+javascript) to an iFrame without having to re-write tons of code (in my naivety I thought simply invoking the page inside an iFrame using target='' in the href would work)? Or is there a better method of accomplishing what I'm trying to do? Maybe iFrame isn't the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Content in iframes remain autonomous from the wrapper app, so it makes sense that it's not working correctly. Other than building a listener for a click event associated with the div wrapped around the iframe, the iframe document isn't accessible if it points to a different origin. (See [same-origin policy]
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy))

**To stay with simple html/css/js solution:**
You can use a regular div to wrap each 'stand-alone' content and then just use whatever button/navigation target you have display that div and hide the previous by changing their css display style with the onClick event.

**More invasive option:**
You may want to consider using a more modular JS approach, like React JS, to build components vs pages and utilize React's structure to toggle components.

With react you can render each 'tool' when the user selects it . You would be able to utilize React component state as well to help in storing data and such for the life-cycle of the component.

Comment: What I was afaid of. Was trying to avoid a major re-write but it looks like that won't be possible. Thanks mandajoan!